# Как достать url из строки? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

```
string = 'https://vk.com/video_hls.php?dirs[240]=https://pvv4.vkuservideo.net/c515336/3/ef3Ojk4MzQ-PzMx/videos/&'
```

Как мне достать https://pvv4.vkuservideo.net/c515336/3/ef3Ojk4MzQ-PzMx/videos/ от 'dirs[240]=' до '&'?

Нужна реализация при помощи библиотеки re

Comment: `f'https://{string.split("//")[-1][:-1]}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
import re

string = 'https://vk.com/video_hls.php?dirs[240]=https://pvv4.vkuservideo.net/c515336/3/ef3Ojk4MzQ-PzMx/videos/&'
r = re.compile('=(.*?)&')
result = re.findall(r, string)
print(result)
```